# Laravel 5.8 @csrf and @method not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf, laravel-5.8

When using the `@csrf` and the `@method('')` it shows correctly on the page code but doesn't work. Either fails with `419` error code or the original method isn't allowed for this page type error.

Using the "old" code seems to work

```
            @csrf

            {{ csrf_field() }}


            @if(isset($post))

                @method('PUT')

                {{method_field('PUT')}}

            @endif
```

The `csrf_field` and `method_field` options work even though they show the same values in the page code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="hTLipJaANmyR2I9VPyF7QvUKDiQlte7BAoRLjqeN">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="hTLipJaANmyR2I9VPyF7QvUKDiQlte7BAoRLjqeN">

<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"> 

<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear to me, please can you edit your question and add a minimal example of your form and your routes. Also I don't understand if `@csfr` and `@method` show up in your rendered html.

Comment: Dparoli , the new standard way of calling for a csrf token is to use '@csrf right ? When I do the html gets rendered with a hidden csrf token but I still get 419 error. When I replace it with {{ csrf_field() }} it also renders the html to look the same but I don't get the 419 error anymore. The same thing happens with '@method and @method('PUT') . Not sure if I am the only one having this issue  because I "did" something wrong or Laravel issue . But at least there is a way to make it work.

Comment: I am not sure if the routes file control this behavior but if it does I would like to understand how/why , I am new to Laravel so any help is appreciated.

Comment: if the generated html is the same you should have other problems